# Effective way to plot values with a vast difference between them

Tags: tables, pgfplots, plot, graphs, best-practices

Here's a nice simple bar graph. It's effective when the plotted values are in the same kind of ballpark, but when there's an outlier, it can put things out of wack.

For instance, I want to plot some values where:
the lowest value is 90,000,000 (90 Million);
the second highest is 500,000,000 (500 Million);
the highest value is 3,000,000,000 (3,000 Million);  <sup>†3 Billion (short scale)</sup>

First of all, the bars would slide ride off the page. Even if I shift the decimal point.

Second point is, it effects the actual figures displayed on the graph.

Third point is, most of the values are towards the low end of the scale (around 100 million), so most of the bars are very small, and there is just this one massive bar. What's the solution?

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=10, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{barlabels/.style={font=\footnotesize\sffamily}, declare function={barheight=5pt;}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.3cm, x=0.06cm]
\foreach [count=\i from 0] \p/\t in{
    10.1/Argentina,
    50.0/Armenia,
    300.0/Belgium,
    10.2/Brazil,
    10.3/Bulgaria,
    9.0/Canada,
    9.5/China,
    11.0/Taiwan,
    10.7/Czechia,
    9.9/Finland}
{\node [anchor=base east, barlabels, name=i-\i] at (0,-\i) {\t};
\fill [blue!40] (i-\i.base east) rectangle ++(\p,barheight) ++(0,-barheight) node[barlabels, black, anchor=base west] {\p};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How about taking the logarithm?

Comment: @marmot Actually, that was my first thought, but I'm a bit out of my element here, I wasn't sure if that was a weird thing to do, or even how to do it, or if it would maybe even defeat the purpose of a visual representation. I'm not sure. I defer to your expertise. I actually thought maybe a pie chart would be a good way to mitigate some of the problems, but it was a bit ugly.

Comment: The design of your data visualisation is really off topic here, but if the chart isn't helping (and it isn't, really) I would just tabulate the numbers.

Comment: It really depends what you want to do. You can also introduce a discontinuity symbol (see section 4.9.12 of the pgfplots manual for the meaning and usage). Or make the bars 3-dimensional such that they only scale with 3rd root of the value.

Comment: @marmot If the logarithm method is an appropriate thing to do, I'm open to that. Can LaTeX calculate it? Or the 3-dimensional thing you said that I don't understand is probably good too. I'll take any advice I can get! :)

Comment: an easy solution would be to give the long bar a length that is obviously way bigger than the others but not excessively long and then just make a note there that reads like "not to scale" followed by the REAL value you want to show. i suppose everybody will understand that. if you are writing a document you also can explicitly tell the reader about that. maybe in an ironic manner like "i obviously had to scale down that value because else the bars would blow the page..."

Comment: Actually, I was able to scale it down to a suitable size by adjusting the length of all the bars by `-13*0.6` or something like that. I figure if I apply the same thing to each bar, it's still be relative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are two options: a discontinuity that gets inserted whenever the bar is above a user-specified cutoff and logs. It all depends on what you want to achieve. If you really just want to present the values as they are, then a table as suggested by David Carlisle may be the best.

```
\documentclass[margin=10,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{barlabels/.style={font=\footnotesize\sffamily}, 
declare function={barheight=5pt;}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.3cm, x=0.06cm]
\begin{scope}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cutoff}{70}
\foreach [count=\i from 0] \p/\t in{
    10.1/Argentina,
    50.0/Armenia,
    300.0/Belgium,
    10.2/Brazil,
    10.3/Bulgaria,
    9.0/Canada,
    9.5/China,
    11.0/Taiwan,
    10.7/Czechia,
    9.9/Finland}
{\node [anchor=base east, barlabels, name=i-\i] at (0,-\i) {\t};
\ifdim\p pt<\cutoff pt
\fill [blue!40] (i-\i.base east) rectangle ++(\p,barheight) ++(0,-barheight) node[barlabels, black, anchor=base west] {\p};
\else
\fill [blue!40] (i-\i.base east) rectangle ++({\cutoff+ln(\p)},barheight) ++(0,-barheight) node[barlabels, black, anchor=base west] {\p};
\fill [white] ([xshift={((\cutoff+ln(\p))/2-1)*0.06cm}]i-\i.base east)  
to[out=45,in=-135,looseness=2] 
++(0,barheight) -- ++ (2,0) to[out=-135,in=45,looseness=2] ++(0,-barheight);
\fi}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[yshift=-4cm]
\foreach [count=\i from 0] \p/\t in{
    10.1/Argentina,
    50.0/Armenia,
    300.0/Belgium,
    10.2/Brazil,
    10.3/Bulgaria,
    9.0/Canada,
    9.5/China,
    11.0/Taiwan,
    10.7/Czechia,
    9.9/Finland}
{\node [anchor=base east, barlabels, name=i-\i] at (0,-\i) {\t};
\fill [blue!40] (i-\i.base east) rectangle ++({10*log10(\p)},barheight) ++(0,-barheight) node[barlabels, black, anchor=base west] {\p};
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: looks good, but can i overwrite the labels to look like `3,000,000,000` or `3 Billion`, etc?

Comment: @tjt263 You only need to replace `node[barlabels, black, anchor=base west] {\p}` by `node[barlabels, black, anchor=base west] {\p~billion}` or sth like that.

Comment: I see, but then wouldn't it be `300.0 billion`? I'll try it in a moment.